# Okay to auto-shutoff LED monitors/displays/screens after 1 minute to save power?

Tags: display, power-management, external-display, laptop-display, energy-saving

With modern LED computer displays is there any physical harm in having them auto-shutoff after 1 or 2 minutes of inactivity?  This could potentially result in the monitor being powered on and off over 100 times each day.

For the context of this question, let's define "modern" as displays manufactured in 2010 or later.

Also, for the context of this question, let's include external monitors as well as integrated laptop screens.

The goal is to reduce energy/power use and cost (expense).

Comment: @Mokubai Perhaps a good electrical engineer knows?  At least what we *do know for sure* is that when the screen is powered down, it uses ***much*** less electricity.

Comment: Your question was: Is it OK to ajuto shut down the monitor. And, yes, it is OK.

Comment: No, it doesn't damage the hardware and this can be configured in Windows' Power Settings.

Answer (score 1):

There is no damage to the monitor by shutting it down.

So if you wish to auto shut down the monitor to save on energy, you can do that safely.

All my monitors black out after 15 minutes and I can shut down the one separate monitor with no damage or ill effects.